# How do you set viewpoint meta tag so that my HTML written webpage displays at the correct scale on a mobile phone?

Tags: html

##Why wont this code display my webpage at the correct size on a mobile phone? The meta tag isn't doing anything##

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
    <h3 style"color: #5e9ca0;">MIEJ at SU Email Campaign</h3>
    <p>
    <a href="mailto:aramosri@syr.edu?subject=Voter Demanding You Addrress the Covid- 
    19 Pandemic in Prisons">Default Device Mail App</a>
    </p>
    <p>
    <a
    href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#compose&su=Voter 
    Demanding You Address the Covid-19 Pandemic in Prisons">Gmail</a>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is (in your opinion) "the correct size"? In fact, this code *is*  displayed at "the correct size", i.e. with the browser's default settings if you don't have any CSS defined.

Answer (score -2):

Add a media query of a mobile screen size, the meta tag is going to allow ur work to show at d screen size of ur PC not that of a mobile phone so add a media query of a mobile screen size that's in ur stylesheet.

Comment: Tom, welcome to Stack Overflow. I hope this question is a joke if so HAHA, if not may this be a good life lesson for you. You cannot take the time to write 'your' or 'the'. This is an easy question, before you ask a question, please so some effort on your part. Last point, always show your code.